# The zeta function has infinitely many zeros in $0<\Re{s}<1/2$?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions, riemann-hypothesis

The following paragraph appears on page 42 in the book *Rational Number Theory in the 20th Century: From PNT to FLT* (Par Wladyslaw Narkiewicz):

> The fact that the strip $0<\Re{s}<1/2$ contains infinitely many zeros of the zeta-function follows from the formula for the number of zeros lying in the rectangle $0<\Re{s}<1/2$, $0<\Im{s}<T$, conjectured by Riemann and established by H. von Mangoldt in 1895: $$N(T)=\frac{1}{2\pi}T\log\left(\frac{T}{2\pi}\right)-\frac{T}{2\pi}+R(T)$$ with $R(T)=O(\log^2T)$.
>
> ([image of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lI1pL.png))

Wouldn't this contradict the Riemann hypothesis?

Comment: Looking at some other sources, it appears that to be a typo: It should be "$0<\Re s<1$" not "$0<\Re s <1/2"$, i.e. the number of zeros in the critical strip.

Comment: I've voted to reopen, since the OP is right, this is a (very unfortunate) typo.

Comment: The typo could be too $0<\Re{s}<1/2$ instead of $\,0<\Re{s}\le 1/2\,$ since any zero in $1/2<\Re{s}<1$ would have a counterpart in  $0<\Re{s}<1/2$ from the functional equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at some other sources, it appears that to be a typo: It should be "$0<\Re s<1$" not "$0<\Re s<1/2$", i.e. the number of zeros in the critical strip.

In fact, no non-trivial zeros of the Riemann Zeta function occur outside the critical strip, so this restriction is superfluous i.e. the formula gives the number of zeroes in $0 <\Im s<T$. It is in this form that [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann-von_Mangoldt_formula) and [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Riemann-vonMangoldtFormula.html) state the Riemann-von Mangoldt formula. Technical sources can be found in both links.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if it were correct, the Riemann hypothesis would be false. It's definitely a typo, however. You can see, for example, [here](http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/mfms/notes_2013-14/02c_counting_zeros_of_zeta.pdf) for a fairly detailed proof; suffice to say that nothing can be done to cut the region of validity down effectively, due to the difficult nature of the $\zeta$-function's behaviour in the critical strip.